# ValueError: time data '23/11/2022' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)

Tags: python, datetime

I have user-entered data where some people put the date as 'm/d/y' while others entered it as 'd/m/y'. I am trying to convert the column to datetime using try except blocks. But it keeps throwing me this error

```
ValueError: time data '23/11/2022' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

I know it doesn't match the format as 23 is not a month, but this is exactly why I am using the try and except blocks.

```
date_df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['11/23/2022', '23/11/2022']})

try:
    date_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(date_df['timestamp'], format = '%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
except ValueError: 
    date_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(date_df['timestamp'], format = '%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

It seems like the try block is not even executing. The result should be:

```
timestamp
23/11/2022
23/11/2022
```

Comment: The code in your `except` block is probably throwing a further exception. Essentially: the `try` block tries to convert the *entire column* using `%d/%m/%Y`. If that fails, the `except` block tries to convert the *entire column* using `%d/%m/%Y`. Neither of those formats will work for the entire column.

Comment: While it is obvious for `23/11/2022` that the day comes first, what about `05/06/2023`? I think the only option you have here is to infer the format from the context; you can't just hope for your `try/except` to select the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try is executing, it's just when it gets to the `except`, it is trying the second datetime conversion on all values in the series, hence the error. You need a function to handle the conversion value by value instead:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convert(dt):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')


date_df['timestamp'] = date_df['timestamp'].apply(convert)
```

Though upon further inspection, the first arm of the `try` block is really just returning `dt`, so I'd recommend:

```py
def convert(dt):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value with regular expressions.

```
import re


date = "12/19/2023"

regular_expression_of_d_m_y = '^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/\d{4}$'
regular_expression_of_m_d_y = '^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{4}$'

if re.search(regular_expression_of_d_m_y, date):
    print('Yes you have d/m/y')
elif re.search(regular_expression_of_m_d_y, date):
    print('Yes you have m/d/y')
```

But you have a problem with your data. When you find a date for example 02/03/2023. How would you know if its 02 of March or 03 of February ?